# Enclosing curly braces in parenthesis with Vim?

Tags: vim

How to enclose curly braces in parenthesis in vim?
Initial string:

```
{a: b}
```

Final string:

```
({a: b})
```

The string possibly span multilines:

```
{
  a: b
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are in normal mode and on any curly bracket character (opening or closing).
The manual/vanilla version (without any bracketing plugin) would be

```
c%(^R")
```

With:

- `^R` meaning `CTRL+R`
- the default register (`"`) being filled with the content of the dictionary.
- `ca{` that should be used instead of `c%` if you're anywhere within the dictionary.

With my [lh-brackets plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets), I would use `v%(` or `vi{(` -- unlike the vanilla version, will leave the default register unmodified.

With the popular [surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround), I guess (I may be wrong as I've been using my plugin for decades) it would be something like `ys%(` or `ysa{(`.

PS: the fact your dictionary spans on several lines doesn't make any difference  here.

Comment: `ysa{)` if you don't want the spaces inside the braces.

Answer (score 4):

With the `vim-surround` plugin you can visually select the text first e.g. `va{`, then surround with parentheses using `S)`. I find it easier to remember this visual surround sequence `v{motion}S<char>` than the other options